# libnfc: "No NFC device found."

Tags: nfc

I use RC-S330 for my development with libnfc and it works well. When I run 'nfc-list', 'NFC device: Sony /  - PN533 v1.48 (0x07) opened' appear.

Recently I bought a RC-S320 and tried to run 'nfc-list', but 'No NFC device found.' appeared.

When I look 'lsusb', 
the result for RC-S330 is:

```
          Product ID: 0x02e1
          Vendor ID: 0x054c  (Sony Corporation)
          Version: 1.30
          Speed: Up to 12 Mb/sec
          Manufacturer: Sony
          Location ID: 0xfa130000 / 6
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Current Required (mA): 200
```

the result for RC-S320 is:

```
          Product ID: 0x01bb
          Vendor ID: 0x054c  (Sony Corporation)
          Version: 1.28
          Speed: Up to 1.5 Mb/sec
          Location ID: 0xfd120000 / 4
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Current Required (mA): Unknown (Device has not been configured)
```

How can I use RC-S320 with libnfc?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the RC-S320 is not on the supported hardware list: http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Devices_compatibility_matrix